# Webassembly - Is it possible to GET/Fetch JSON data from an API and manipulate in JS?

Tags: javascript, rest, fetch, emscripten, webassembly

I'm new to webassembly, and trying to manipulate JSON data that is fetched from a file or url in a Webassembly compiled module, and getting that JSON in Javascript so I can read and manipulate it there.

The only example I found was from https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/api_reference/fetch.html on dling from a file and saving it to the browser IndexedDB, but the result is unreadable bytes, not the JSON

fetch.c :

```
void downloadSucceeded(emscripten_fetch_t *fetch) {
printf("Finished downloading %llu bytes from URL %s.\n", fetch->numBytes, fetch->url);
// The data is now available at fetch->data[0] through fetch->data[fetch->numBytes-1];
emscripten_fetch_close(fetch); // Free data associated with the fetch.
}

void downloadFailed(emscripten_fetch_t *fetch) {
printf("Downloading %s failed, HTTP failure status code: %d.\n", fetch->url, fetch->status);
emscripten_fetch_close(fetch); // Also free data on failure.
}

int main() {
emscripten_fetch_attr_t attr;
emscripten_fetch_attr_init(&attr);
strcpy(attr.requestMethod, "GET");
attr.attributes = EMSCRIPTEN_FETCH_LOAD_TO_MEMORY | EMSCRIPTEN_FETCH_PERSIST_FILE;
attr.onsuccess = downloadSucceeded;
attr.onerror = downloadFailed;
emscripten_fetch(&attr, "./json/bol_list1.json");
}
```

Compiling this to .js works, the console logs it downloaded 16507 bytes from the JSON file, and it is inserted into IndexedDB but the result is not readable as it doesn't resemble the JSON
JSON file : https://pastebin.com/WBJrYgPR

IndexDB result: 
[image: IndexedDB result screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

That is a byte string. The bytes in your screenshot are `123 034 111 114 105 110 097 108 082 101 113 117 101 115 034 058` or `"{"orinalReques":`.

Assuming the string is utf-8 decode with:

```js
var enc = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
enc.decode(array);
```